# Unity with Bullet Physics : rigidbody position accuracy

Tags: unity-game-engine, bulletphysics, bullet

I'm lifting a rigidbody up to a position (target) on Y-Axis by AddForce or set velocity. Then rigidbody will stop and stay still on a target's position.

I want to check when the rigidbody position is equal or as close as possible to the target.

I have tried with PhysicsX ,the default physics engine.
It's work fine with following information.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(Rigidbody.position.y >= 0.6)
    {
        //Stop Rigidbody
    }
}
```

Target is 0.6, the rigidbody stop at 0.6045592 on Y-Axis.
And **the rigidbody stop at 0.6045592 after run every time.**
That is what i want, stop at same position every time and very small error value.

For some reasons, I switch from PhysicsX to Bullet Physics with [this asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/physics/bullet-physics-for-unity-62991).

Unlike Unity's Rigidbody, BRigidBody doesn't contain position variable. So i have to access transform.position instead.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(BulletRigidbody.transform.position.y >= 0.6)
    {
        //Stop Bullet Rigidbody
    }
}
```

With Bullet,  when target is 0.6 , the rigidbody stop at 0.6720, 0.72, 0.8.

The error value is very big and each time that run is not the same value.

---

*Both examples use fixedTimeStep = 0.02 and use same lift up velocity.*

How can i fix the Bullet Physics Example?
I want to reduce the error value and stop rigidbody at the same position every time i run.

I think, i am wrong access BRigidbody.transform.position. It should be something else.
Or i shouldn't check condition inside FixedUpdate() but somewhere else.

Here is just a screenshot.

[image]

Thanks.

-- I have tried change fixedTimeStep to lower value , it doesn't help much and make more lag.

Comment: You could just set the position to `0.6` within your `if`. So in the case your rigidbody "overshoots" the target from one frame/FixedUpdate to another it just is set fix to the position you want it. Anyway if you always want this thing to move to a certain position you really should have a look into [Animations](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/s/animation) instead of doing it by physics/calculation!

Comment: I always want to lift this green plate up because i will put some small objects over it. So if i lift the green plate up , the small objects will move up with the green plate velocity and angular velocity. @derHugo